# Can I add a number to an interval?

Tags: notation

This is a question about notation (trust me, I did a lot of googling and have been unable to find the answer). I am supposed to find the domain of
$$\sqrt{\frac{x}{\sin(x)}}$$ and I have found it.

I want to show that for positive part of the real axis, the domain is
$$(0,\pi),(2\pi,3\pi),\dots$$ I have the negative part as well but it is irrelevant to the question.

The question is whether it is correct to write this as
$$(0,\pi)+k2\pi, k \in \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$$

Comment: i would not understand that notation if I saw it without all the preamble.  Why not write it as $ \cup_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(2k\pi, (2k+1)\pi\right)$ or something like that?

Comment: It’s best to just take the union, that way you have one concrete set which is the domain.

Comment: It is certainly worth writing something like "$\ldots,(-3\pi,-2\pi),(-\pi,0),(0,\pi),(2\pi,3\pi),\ldots$, i.e. $\bigcup\limits_{ k \in \mathbb Z_{\ge 0}} (-\pi-2k\pi,0-2k\pi)\cup (0+2k\pi,\pi+2k\pi)$" or whatever notation-heavy version you decide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Lulu in the comments, what you wrote is better written as:

$$ \bigcup_{k=0}^{\infty}\ (\ 2k\pi,\ (2k+1)\pi\ ) $$

Also, you haven't found the entire possible domain. There are negative values of $x$ that work also (Hint: what negative values of $x$ make $\sin x$ negative?)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did, however, find the entire domain as I mentioned in my post "I have the negative part as well but it is irrelevant to the question."

Answer (score 0):

*Correct* is subjective. I guess that *understood* is the right criterion.

This notation is not common, though it is in fact elegant and makes obvious the fact that the interval is translated. See the other reactions.

---

Other options:  $$x-2k\pi\in(0,\pi), k\in\mathbb N_0$$

or

$$x\bmod2\pi\in(0,\pi),x\ge0.$$

Comment: Your answer is incorrect, or perhaps I misunderstand...